# Нам [нейросети] не нужны!

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

У нас есть метки [нейронные-сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8) включает 56 вопросов/7 подписчиков и метка [нейросети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8) включает 3 вопроса/0 подписчиков.
Предлагаю удалить метку [нейросети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8) или сделать синонимом для [нейронные-сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8).

Comment: Предлагаю по традиции заголовок "[нейросети] не нужны"

Comment: @soon готово ))